# Purim 2020 Skype megilla leining recommendation

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, megillat-esther, leniencies, shaat-hadechak

Due to the 2020 Coronavirus epidemic, many are unable to go to shul this year to hear the Megilla. For those who are unable to find a private reading and are without their own Megilla, they have limited options.

Harav Hershel Schachter has ruled that, for this year's unique extenuating circumstances, it is worthwhile to listen to a live broadcast of the Megilla from Shul rather than miss Megilla reading altogether. Others have ruled similarly. For those who are relying on this leniency, what are sites that broadcast the reading live, e.g. for the zmanim of EST?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeshiva University sent out an announcement for their live webcast for 2020:

Monday night 7:55 PM EDT

Tuesday morning 8:45 AM EDT

Available at yutorah.org/live

[image: screenshot of announcement]

Comment: Is there any point to keeping this answer posted on the internet anymore?

Comment: Even after that, it is historically significant to document that YU chose to do this broadcast this year.  They might or might not in the future.

Comment: @MikeSupportsMonica Historically significant??? What an overstatement.

Comment: @DoubleAA Eh, maybe your view of history is different than mine. It would be easy to imagine someone studying how religious organizations changed policies during a epidemic or an epidemic scare. I'm pretty sure that hearing it through a speaker instead of live is not encouraged most of the time.

Comment: @DoubleAA YU doing it this year implies they'd be likely to do it again if ch"v it's necessary, which would help people know where to look in future years.

Comment: @MikeSupportsMonica How is this a change in policy?  Hearing the megillah through a live broadcast works according to some opinions but not all, and fulfilling your obligation according to some opinions is better than nothing.  That's true every year.  It just happens that this year there are a lot of people who have no other choice. (though I'd encourage every family to buy a kosher megillah so that you never have to deal with these issues).

Comment: With just about 6 weeks to go to Purim 2021, have any live webcasts for this year been announced?